# How to get a reference to the node from other class?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any simple way to get a reference to control of a stage from other class? It seems to be a problem in every GUI based framework except Delphi. If only `Controller` or `Main` class were static...

Here is my code:

**Controller.java**:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button algorithms;

    @FXML
    private Button settings;

    @FXML
    private Button run;

    @FXML
    public TextArea console; // I want access that node from class named 'Utils'

    @FXML
    void initialize() { }

    public Controller () { }

    @FXML
    private void onRun() {
        Utility.get().runBench();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onSettings() {
        console.appendText("I am opening settings...");
    }

    @FXML
    private void onAlgorithm() {
        console.appendText("I am opening list of Algorithms...");
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**:

```
package sample;

import sample.Algorithms.BubbleSort;

import java.util.*;


// Singleton
public class Utility {
    private static Utility ourInstance = new Utility();

    public static Utility get() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private Utility() {
        listOfAlgorithms.add(new BubbleSort(howManyN));
    }

    List<Algorithm> listOfAlgorithms = new LinkedList<>();
    Long howManyN = 999L;

    public void runBench() {
        for (Algorithm a: listOfAlgorithms) {
            double start = System.nanoTime();
            a.run();
            double end = System.nanoTime();
            double result = end - start;
            System.out.println(
//            console.appendText(  // Accessing like that would be ideal
                    "Algorithm: " + a.getClass().getName() + "\n" +
                    "For N = " + a.getN() + " time is: " + result
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I heard about FXMLoader, but it is in `Main` Class, so there is no difference.

**Main.java**:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    final String APP_NAME = "SortAll 2";
    final String RES_PATH = "../resources/scene.fxml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(RES_PATH));
        primaryStage.setTitle(APP_NAME);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically shouldn't do this: it violates encapsulation. The controller should be the only object that "knows about" the controls. It wouldn't make any sense for the controller to be static, because there would be no way to load the same FXML file twice (you would only have one controller for two sets of UI controls).

Comment: If you really want to do that, pass your variable to your util method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an object to the `runBench()` method that describes what you want to do with the result. Since you're encapsulating the result as a `String`, you could use a [`Consumer<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

```
public void runBench(Consumer<String> onAlgorithmCompletion) {
    for (Algorithm a: listOfAlgorithms) {
        double start = System.nanoTime();
        a.run();
        double end = System.nanoTime();
        double result = end - start;
        onAlgorithmCompletion.accept(
                "Algorithm: " + a.getClass().getName() + "\n" +
                "For N = " + a.getN() + " time is: " + result
        );
    }
}
```

Then from your controller you can do

```
@FXML
private void onRun() {
    Utility.get().runBench(console::appendText);
}
```

---

This is unrelated to the question you posted, but you almost certainly need to execute your `runBench()` method in a background thread, since it apparently takes some time to execute. If you do that, you need to ensure that the console is only accessed on the FX Application Thread. The above solution is easy to modify to do this (your `runBench(...)` method doesn't need to change at all):

```
private Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

// ...

@FXML
private void onRun() {
    exec.execute(() -> Utility.get().runBench(
        result -> Platform.runLater(console.appendText(result))));
}
```

Comment: @Barburka `Consumer<String>` is an interface that has a single abstract method, `public void accept(String value)`. The method reference `console::appendText` (effectively; it doesn't really work like this) creates an object that implements that interface with `public void accept(String value) { console.appendText(value);}`.

Comment: Now I really understand, what I was doing wrong - classes shouldn't know about each other. Nice trick with this consumer

Answer (score 2):

Umm, can't you just pass console as a runBench() parameter?

**Utility.java**:

```
 public void runBench(TextArea console) {
    for (Algorithm a: listOfAlgorithms) {
        double start = System.nanoTime();
        a.run();
        double end = System.nanoTime();
        double result = end - start;
        System.out.println(
        console.appendText(
                "Algorithm: " + a.getClass().getName() + "\n" +
                "For N = " + a.getN() + " time is: " + result
        );
    }
}
```

and

**Controller.java**:

```
@FXML
private void onRun() {
    Utility.get().runBench(console);
}
```

Comment: Better: pass a `Consumer<String>` instead, to avoid exposing the UI controls (and maintain flexibility, etc).

Comment: Or you can build and return text string in runBench() and append it directly into controller method for better encapsulation.

EDIT: You got better idea Mr Up :)

Comment: I can, but it can't be correct solution. Perhaps I will have 1000 methods in 1000 classes. In every I should pass that parameters? What if I had 20 nodes in my stage, I want to access them all. What then?

Comment: @Barburka What's wrong with the suggestion I made in the comment above?

Comment: Can't comment on direct answer (newb here), but I can do it here.
Very basic speaking: Consumer is a generic functional interface which allows you to pass a method as a parameter and execute it inside with specified type parameter.